# How do I set focus on first column after selecting Reset button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a page that needs to be accessible through keyboard. Everything works fine but I am not sure how to set focus on the Name column (first dropdwon) after I hit Filter Results button? I tired the following code but it doesn't work -

```
$(".dropdown1").focus();
```

Is there a way to set focus on spanid? or what's the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Here is the link to my code - https://live.datatables.net/datubino/10/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      target: 6,
      visible: false,
      searchable: true,
    }],
    dom: 'ilfrt<"left-col"B><"toolbar"><"right-col"p>',
    fnInitComplete: function() {
      $('div.toolbar').html('<p>Custom tool bar!</p>');
    },
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        className: 'mybutton',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible'
        }
      },
     //  'colvis'
    ],
  });
  buildSelect(table);
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });

  $('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $(".dropdown1").focus();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">select me</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    if (column.index() === 0) {
      var filteredNames = column.data().unique().toArray();
      ['Garrett', 'Test1', 'Ashton'].forEach((d) => {
        if (filteredNames.includes(d)) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
        }
      });
    } else {
      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
      });
    }

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>
<div class="searchbox">
  <p>Name:
    <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
  </p>
  <p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
  </p>
  <p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="myInput">Filter</button>
  <button type="button" id="test">Reset</button>
</div>
<table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
      <th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
      <th>&#160;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Hidden Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>test4</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
      <td>Sys Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Director: fgghghjhjhjhkjkj</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
      <td>Director:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Technical Authorjkjkjk fdfd h gjjjhjhk</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
      <td>Tech author</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `.dropdown1` is a class selector, `dropdown1` is an id though. Use the proper id selector and include the select element as that is the element you are actually wanting to focus, eg `$('#dropdown1 select')`

Comment: if you did wanted to focus a span, then you could set the `tabindex="0"` on the element

Comment: Thankyou Patrick Evans, it worked!

Comment: Formatted your code and your HTML is not really valid.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is wrong with mt HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#` instead of `.` to target an id and use the child combinator (`>`) to get the `<select>` element inside that `<span>`.

```js
$("#dropdown1 > select").focus();
```